# Why Luks only asks for password once at boot for 2 devices?

Tags: boot, mount, password, encryption, luks

I have the following lines in /etc/crypttab:

```
cryptswap1 /dev/sda2 none luks
hd-crypt UUID=xxxx none luks
```

and both use the same luks password.

The behaviour of Ubuntu upon boot is:

> Please enter password for device cryptswap1.
>   Boot finishes.

hd-crypt is decrypted too (and mounted via fstab).

Which underlying technology ensures that hd-crypt is decrypted with the password of cryptswap? It is indeed the same password, but I don’t see which mechanism passes the password on and why Ubuntu does not ask me twice. I think this behaviour is great, as so I can protect all my disks via a strong password of swap which secures hibernate -resume (as upon resume all decrypted devices are still decrypted).

I have 2 ideas:

- Keyslot mechanism: both devices use keyslot 0
- some [60 second password caching is happening?](https://www.enricozini.org/blog/2015/debian/crypttab-reuse-passwords/)

Comment: What are to contents of your `/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_keyctl`?

Comment: i copied it to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/HxUYQ8i9

Comment: You're asking too many questions in one question...  Abandoning answer, sorry, I don't know everything you want to know.

Comment: Edited, removed 2nd question.

Comment: I'm not sure how luks works so posting as a comment and invite correction if I am wrong. Typically, the passphrase is not your decrypt key, but rater the password to a keyring that has the key stored in it. Thus, entering the password unlocks the keyring and gives access to the keys stored there for a certain amount of time. It is possible that all partitions/drives with the same passphrase are stored in the same keyring.